# Whenever I am getting my spark job in dockercontainer,I am getting Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, docker-compose, spark-streaming

The error I am getting is:-

`20/11/02 13:34:51 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-366ac503-c5a4-4338-869c-84786983aab3--188679505-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-366ac503-c5a4-4338-869c-84786983aab3--188679505-driver-0] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected`

My docker-compose.yml file

```
 version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
    - 2181:2181

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
    - 9092:9092
    
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "kafkatutorial:1:1"
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
      SSL: localhost:9092
    expose:
     - 9092
      
  spark:
   build:
    dockerfile: DockerFileSpark
    context: .

   
   environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
   
   ports:
      - '8080:8080'
   links:
    - kafka
   
   depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    - kafka
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `SSL: localhost:9092` is not a valid environment variable for the kafka container ; you need to set SSL up in the two listener variables **and** add ssl certificates to the image
2. Not clear where your Spark code is running, but within a container, `localhost` will never work to connect to an external service. Remove the `links`in your yaml and connect to `kafka:9092` in the code

Comment: If you have a mentor, then he/she should be teaching you. Your past two issues have been Docker networking issues, not Kafka related. Simply adding Spark to that process is too much at once